# API functions defined in the CUDA run-time environment

Tags: api, cuda, runtime

Some CUDA APIs are defined in the run-time environment like cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy, cudaFree and i understand that because all of them has some thing to do during the run-time(For example, cudaMalloc, like malloc in c, do the dynamic memory allocation during run-time). But i don't get why some functions like cudaGetDeviceProperties are defined there, can't them be just defined in an ordinary header file?
are all CUDA APIs in run-time environment?

Answer (score 2):

The runtime functions are declared in an ordinary header file, it is `cuda_runtime.h`

With the exception of kernel launches, you can build all cuda runtime API functionality using g++ (for example, or cl.exe, on windows) by including `cuda_runtime.h` and linking against an appropriate cudart (cuda runtime library) for your OS (e.g. `-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart` on linux.

The reason you may not see this ordinarily is because, when compiling with `nvcc` (a compiler-driver that calls the host compiler under the hood, amongst other things), this include and library linkage are taken care of for you by `nvcc`, there is no need to specify them explicitly.

Most CUDA runtime functions interact in some fashion with the CUDA GPU driver.  There isn't any distinction, I don't think, between `cudaMalloc` and `cudaGetDeviceProperties`, in this respect.

The primary API distinction in CUDA is the [runtime API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#axzz3OjtACNuk) and the [driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#axzz3OjtACNuk).  These API's are largely comparable, having mostly similar functions that do similar things.  They serve slightly different purposes, however, and [the driver API gives some additional flexibility](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#driver-api) (such as kernel launches from a file compiled with the host compiler, and JIT-compilation of PTX modules) that are not all entirely possible with the runtime API.